# SQL Check constraint for date range <VALID_FROM, VALID_TO>

Tags: sql, oracle, check-constraints

Given I have 2 db table columns VALID_FROM, VALID_TO and they form date range from domain perspective.

How to make sure VALID_TO is not before VALID_FROM when being inserted?

I assume check constraint could help.

How would one look like for Oracle db engine?

Answer (score 2):

In Sql Server we have option of using Check Constraint that is applied on the table before creation.

Example :

```
     CREATE TABLE test6 
   ( 
      id         INT IDENTITY(1, 1), 
      NAME       VARCHAR(50), 
      valid_from DATETIME, 
      valid_to   DATETIME, 
      CONSTRAINT check_valid_to  CHECK (valid_to > valid_from) 
   )
```

I hope it will help you.

And in `Oracle` you can use it as :

```
CREATE TABLE test6
(
   id           NUMBER,
   NAME         VARCHAR (50),
   valid_from   DATE,
   valid_to     DATE,
   CONSTRAINT check_valid_to CHECK (valid_to > valid_from)
)
```